# Lazy list, converting JSON string into String array

Tags: android, arrays, json

I know this must be a simple error, but i cant figure it out. I am trying to get a list of image url from a json Array and input it into a string array. getting the list of image url is easy, but putting it into the String array im stuck at that part.

**///edited**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.6/webservice/events.php";
    private static final String TAG_IMG = "event_img";
    private static String myevent_img = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventsList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
        JSONArray jArray = null;
        JSONObject json;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");
            Log.d("jarray", "jarray post "+jArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data;
            try {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 myevent_img = json_data.getString(TAG_IMG);
                Log.d("jobj ", "event_img"+myevent_img);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }



    };

    private String[] mStrings={myevent_img
    };
}
```

I dont get any errors in Logcat.

Comment: From the code you post, it's not easy to figure out what's happening. At least post the complete method and any log error you have.

Comment: If i were to log.d myevent_img, i would get the last value it held in the for loop, which is understandable. but even so, String[] mStrings should give me atleast one value.

Comment: Remove the `static` from `myevent_img` because otherwise is always null

Comment: Thank you for reply, but no change.

Comment: Keep in mind im trying to use Lazy list. There must be a way to turn myevent_img into a string array and input it into mStrings, im just not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a List and then return an array. An example :

```
private List<String> _list = null;
private String[] mStrings = null;
```

then inside `onCreate` you initialise & fill the list like that:

```
    _list = new ArrayList<String>();

           ..........
       for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data;
                try {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     myevent_img = json_data.getString(TAG_IMG);
                     _list.add(myevent_img);
                ............
```

and finally you write :

```
mStrings=new String[_list.size()];
mStrings = _list.toArray(mStrings);
```

It's more convenient to  use lists for such things but anyway this is something personal I think.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. t almost worked too. excepted i get an error on **asList**. it says The method asList(List<String>) is undefined for the type Array

Comment: I change a little bit the transformation from list to array. This is the proper way to transform from list to array. Ready to go.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks alot! how ever i did have to put the two last lines inside oncreate aswell for it to work, is that alright in terms of performance , etc ? im using lazy list.

Comment: ArrayList actually uses System.arraycopy() to do this, which is a fast routine and with this way , you say to `toArray()` just simply populate the existing array.